# How to stop adding more items with the same index in $.each loop in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to stop adding more items with the same index in $.each loop in jQuery?

I have this code:

```
var arr = data.errors;
var oneIndexIsEnough = '';

$.each(arr, function(index, value)
{
    if (value.length != 0)
    {

        if (oneIndexIsEnough != index) {
            $("#" + index).after('<span class="text-error validation-error-inline">' + value + '</span>');
            oneIndexIsEnough = index;
        } else {
            //
        }

    }
});
```

And the condition `if (oneIndexIsEnough != index)` is not working in this case.

i dont'want to add more than one error message to the same index e.g. username. How to stop adding additional error messages after the first addition and go to the next index e.g. email?

**UPDATE:**

I could end up with something like this:

```
   index      |           message                    |
-----------------------------------------------------|
   username   |  username could contain only letters |
-----------------------------------------------------|
   username   |  username is not unique              |
-----------------------------------------------------|
   username   |  username can contain only 20 char.  |
-----------------------------------------------------|
   email      |  email is not unique                 |
-----------------------------------------------------|
   email      |  email does have a bad format        |
-----------------------------------------------------|
```

But instead of haveing 5 error messages, I would like to have only these 2.

```
   username   |  username could contain only letters
```

and

```
 email      |  email is not unique
```

how to stop when the name of the index is repeating and jump to the next name(index)?

Comment: Why not make a compacted copy of the array instead?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/

Comment: @Diodeus compacted copy of the array?

Comment: @XaxD that's for DOM not for my JSON array

Comment: I need some kind of `break` e.g. username contains two messages and when each goes through tehm I got with two messages. But I want to got only with the first and then move to the next index e.g. email.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that the problem is that you're only storing the last index you found, what if you use an array to store the processed indexes, and then check if they are already inside?

```
var arr = data.errors;
var processed = [];

$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    if (value.length != 0) {
        if (processed.indexOf(value.index) == -1) {
            // process value.message
            processed.push(value.index);
        } else {
            //
        }
    }
});
```

This will work if the array has a layout similar to:

```
var arr = [
    {
        index: 'username',
        message: 'username could contain only letters'
    }
];
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it still shows all 3 errors instead of just the first for my username ;(

Comment: Ohh we were getting confused by the meaning of the index variable, I updated my answer...

Comment: No, it's still showing all errors on the page. I want to stop adding error messages to the index `username` after the first addition and go to the next index with the name `email` and add the error message there.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if your element already has a *text-error* span as its first sibling.

something like this

```
//I select the first sibling of your index with the class "text-error"
if (!$("#" + index).siblings('span').eq(0).hasClass("text-error")) 
{
    $("#" + index).after('<span class="text-error validation-error-inline">' + value + '</span>');
}
```

It should be easier to prevent multiple error message for the same element that way than keeping track of your index.

Comment: Hmm. I am getting the error `TypeError: $(...).sibling is not a function`